# Mechanism for removal of trimethylsilyl directly bonded to carbons

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organosilicon-compounds

I recently came across a scheme for the synthesis of panacene (Sabot *et al.*, [2008OrgLett4629](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ol801921d)):

[image]

In this synthesis, the step from 14 to 9 in removes  a trimethylsilyl ($\ce{TMS}$) group directly bonded to an aryl ring with $\ce{TBAF}$ (tetra-n-butylammonium fluoride) and $\ce{CsF}$ with $\ce{DMF}$ as the solvent.

I understand that silicon has a strong affinity for Fluoride and am familiar with the mechanism for deprotection of silyl ethers. For silyl ethers the $\ce{RO^-}$ acts as a leaving group from the 5-coordinate silicon. Here, however, the aryl anion seems like a bad leaving group. So, what is the mechanism for this?

Comment: By TMS I assume you mean trimethyl silyl ? You should at least mention what the acronyms mean, because not everyone might be familiar with every aconym. I don't know what TBAF means for example. Also, the paper is behind paywall, so please consider posting a diagram of the synthesis scheme here, otherwise people might not know what you are asking about.

Comment: For future reference: Your question is easier to access (and thus, more likely to receive helping answers / comments) if you may illustrate the reaction by a scheme.  The Org. Lett. paper contains multiple instances where $\ce{C-SiMe3}$ bonds are broken (e.g., equally from a terminal acetylene by moderation of $\ce{AgNO3}$, NBS in acetone), thus it would be a time saver for the reader of your question to see all _at once_.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti It is a guess that this added scheme is about the reaction the OP refers to.

Comment: @Buttonwood Thanks, I will take that into account in my future questions. The image is correct.